# SixLabors: converting img colorspace to sRGB

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, color-space, imagesharp

first off - im not wellversed with colorspaces
so pls forgive me if im not asking the question well or if the answers really obvious

i am using sixlabors imagesharp
and since im getting images from all different and random sources
i want to check each images colorspace
if its not in sRGB then convert it to sRBG

i couldnt find any tutorials on how to use sixlabors on how to set up this conversion
and the doc had so many options that i got lost in it
heres the link to the sixlabors colorspace commands
[sixlabors colorspace conversion](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.ColorSpaces.Conversion.html)

can someone help me and point the way 
or at least send a coupla links on examples how to do this simple conversion using imagesharp?

ps: ive done image mutation and manipulation with imagesharp 
but nothing dealing with colorspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of this writing 
there is no such functionality but it has been ticketed as a to do

there is however a suggested workaround

details here:
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/discussions/1585